# Parallel generation of SystemModel

Tags: system-modeler, system-modeling

I notices that it takes quite a long time to generate a lot of models. Therefore, it occures to me that maybe parallelization would help. However, the following example keeps evaluating and never returns any result.

```
ParallelTable[CreateSystemModel[{y[tau] == x[tau] + 1}, tau, 
    {x \[Element] "RealInput", y \ [Element] "RealOutput"}], {i, 1, 12}]
```

Is there any method to generate `SystemModel` parallelly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to parallelize `CreateSystemModel`.